# R - Get updated count across the years

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains a County Variable (CountyState), a Year variable, the number of monuments in that county (CountPerConty), the number of monuments that were removed in a given year (RemovalsPerCountyYear), and the removal year. My goal is to create a variable that counts the number of monuments in a county in any given year.

Target dataframe looks like this:

```
structure(list(washington = c("DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", 
"DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", 
"DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County"
), year = c("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", 
"2022"), CurrentCount = c("10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "8", 
"8", "7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

That means, if DC Washington County started out with 10 monuments, and 2 get removed in 2020 and 1 gets removed in 2022 , then the counter should show 8 for the year 2020 and 2021, and 7 in the year 2022.

I tried to create the variable like this:

```
df8$CountPerCountyYear <- ifelse(df8$RemovalYear <= df8$YearCount, df8$CountPerCounty - df8$RemovalsPerCountyYear, df8$CountPerCounty)
```

The problem is that this only works in counties where there was only a removal in one year. If there was a removal in multiple years, it doesn't work. Does anyone have ideas how to solve this? Find 100 rows of example data below.

```
structure(list(CountyState = c("DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", 
"DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", 
"DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", 
"DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", 
"DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County", 
"DC, Washington County", "DC, Washington County"), YearCount = c("2020", 
"2020", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2017", "2017", "2018", 
"2018", "2019", "2019", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2016"), CountPerCounty = c(10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
    RemovalsPerCountyYear = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1), RemovalYear = c("2020", "2022", "2020", "2022", 
    "2020", "2022", "2020", "2022", "2020", "2022", "2020", "2022", 
    "2020", "2022", "2020", "2022")), row.names = c(14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 324L, 
325L, 326L, 327L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The sample data has (for example) two rows each for `"DC, Washington County"` in `2020` (and years 2021 and 2022 as well), though other values in that row (that it appears you are trying to calculate) are different; there are four other counties that have duplicated years as well. Further, for `"DC"` again, why in 2020 do we have `"RemovalYear"` of 2022 (in the future from the row's perspective)? It seems trivial enough to have a running count, but duplicating rows and odd columns like that are perplexing.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to clarifiy. "RemovalYear" is the Year a monument got removed. The duplicate rows which only differ in "RemovalYear" indicate that there was a monument removed in that area in 2020, and once in 2022. "YearCount" is simply a count from 2015-2022, and I want to create a variable that decreases every time "RemovalYear" is to "YearCount".

Pseudocode: If(YearCount = RemovalYear){
CurrentCount = CountPerCounty - RemovalsPerYear}. 

The problem is that this only works for the first removal in an area. For the second removal, it will again take the original count

Comment: Can you please show your desired output for `"DC, Washington County"`? That is, as a literal frame? Perhaps the easiest way would be to subset the data and edit the text on the console, then [edit] your question and add to a [code block]. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I simplified the example to only Washington and added the target dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` pipe that gives your desired output:

```r
library(dplyr)
datin %>%
  arrange(YearCount) %>%
  mutate(Removals = if_else(RemovalYear == YearCount, RemovalsPerCountyYear, 0)) %>%
  group_by(CountyState, YearCount) %>%
  summarize(Count = first(CountPerCounty), Removals = sum(Removals)) %>%
  mutate(CurrentCount = Count - cumsum(Removals))
# # A tibble: 8 × 5
#   CountyState           YearCount Count Removals CurrentCount
#   <chr>                 <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 DC, Washington County 2015         10        0           10
# 2 DC, Washington County 2016         10        0           10
# 3 DC, Washington County 2017         10        0           10
# 4 DC, Washington County 2018         10        0           10
# 5 DC, Washington County 2019         10        0           10
# 6 DC, Washington County 2020         10        2            8
# 7 DC, Washington County 2021         10        0            8
# 8 DC, Washington County 2022         10        1            7
```

Brief walkthrough:

- `arrange(.)` because we need the eventual `cumsum` to be order chronologically;
- `mutate` changes the `RemovalsPerCountyYear` so that it only counts if it is "this year" (`YearCount`);
- `group_by` and `summarize` reduce the data here to just one row per county-and-year; we grab the first count and sum of removals so we know how much to remove each year;
- we then remove the cumulative sum of removals into the `CurrentCount` column

The key concepts here are `cumsum(.)` and doing this per-group using `group_by`.

Comment: Thank you, that works! This is also a lot more intuitive than the other answer I found in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

```
df8$YearCount <- as.numeric(df8$YearCount)
df8$RemovalYear <- as.numeric(df8$RemovalYear)

# Sort the dataframe by CountyState, YearCount, and RemovalYear
df8 <- df8[order(df8$CountyState, df8$YearCount, df8$RemovalYear), ]

# Create a new variable to store the count after removals
df8$CountAfterRemoval <- df8$CountPerCounty

# Loop through the rows and update the count after each removal

for (i in 2:nrow(df8)) {
  if (df8$CountyState[i] == df8$CountyState[i - 1]) {
    if (df8$YearCount[i] == df8$RemovalYear[i - 1]) {
      df8$CountAfterRemoval[i] <- df8$CountAfterRemoval[i - 1] - df8$RemovalsPerCountyYear[i - 1]
    } else {
      df8$CountAfterRemoval[i] <- df8$CountAfterRemoval[i - 1]
    }
  }
}
```

This also worked with my dataframe and gave me the desired output. The answer by r2evans is a lot simpler though.

Comment: Realize that your code here works when they are perfectly sorted. I term this "Excel group calculations", since so many people do it this way (I know of no alternatives, it might be the "only way" in Excel). It is fragile to many things, I find functions that natively handle grouping for me are a game-changer in data processing, taking away ambiguities and corner-cases.

Comment: True. But the sorting happens as part of the code. (Before the for loop, so I don't understand how this is different from "arrange"?)

Comment: I'm not saying this doesn't work, I'm saying that in general it is safer to do grouping operations by-group instead of row-by-row. It is also faster, and when your data goes from 10s of rows to 10K or more, you can notice the difference. What I'm trying to say overall is that unless you think this is the last time you'll be doing data munging with groups like this, it is a good habit to shift to more safe/advanced/performant/flexible techniques like group-wise operations instead of row-wise. I'm suggesting shifting gears past "Excel calcs in R".

Comment: An analyst's skills at data munging improve by leaps and bounds when a few concepts are master, imho. Among them: group-wise (instead of row-wise) operations like this; merge/join ops (left, right, inner, full, anti); reshaping/pivoting the data (long-to-wide, wide-to-long); accumulating operations. I'm not saying every data wrangler must know all these perfectly, but if you work with data a lot, generally at least 1-2 of these techniques apply to what you do, and it _transforms and accelerates_ what you are capable of doing.